# Facebook tab app returning a 404 error on a post request to our page on a node.js nginx served paged

Tags: node.js, facebook, nginx

I'm running into an issue with a Facebook tab app I'm trying to create from our application titlepager.com. The https url is returning a 404 error. Facebook apps make a post request and I'm wondering what in our nginx set up needs to change. Is this a node issue? Does nginx have x-frame options on a default? The pages can be successfully iframed into wordpress and wix though so I think it has something to do with the POST request. An example page is https://titlepager.com/9781945473302

I'm somewhat of a newbie with both node and nginx. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely is that you are not handling POST requests

Comment: right . how do I set up nginx to handle post requests?

Comment: Nginx will forward the request whether it is POST or GET to your node app based on the config. So first check what request you are getting at NGINX and why it says 404